# table logic with responsive values bootstrap / html

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I don't think I understand Bootstrap logic quiet well. With code listed down, I defined table-responsive class with 12 units. For each cell within table i then used defined the size.

So basic idea is to get this:

```
  0
1 2 3
```

However bootstrap returns me this:

```
_0_
_1_2 3
```

For the value 1 it takes the parameters of cell with value 0. Why is that, eventhose i defined cell nr.1 can have only one unit size. Please let me know. Thank you.

```
<div class="table-responsive col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">1</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="table-responsive col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-3" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">1</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>   
</div>
```

Comment: may i just ask why rowspan would not work wit this... let say > <...colspan="3" rowspan="3"...> thank you

Comment: `rowspan="3"` will occupy the space of 3 rows but you want your first collumn to occupy space of three columns so that your td should appear in middle. if you want to do this in horizontal arrangement you will use rowspan.

Answer (score 1):

you need to alter your first row like this. You are getting this error because the column structure for each row would be same.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBPREQ) and below is a working example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">

        <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td></td>
                <td class="col-xs-1 col-offset-3" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">1</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this, i have copied your code and  add `display:inline-block` to `td` element try with the snippet

```css
table tr {
    text-align:center;
}
table tr td {
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">0</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">1</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">2</td>
                <td class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;">3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>   
</div>
```